# configure image only for visible row on table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, networking

I'm trying to load my table view with cells that contain images downloaded off the internet. I'd like to only perform the download operation on cells that are currently visible instead of downloading every image as the user scrolls down quickly.

I found this while browsing stackoverflow but it doesn't help much :

```
- (void)configureVisibleCellsForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView animated:(BOOL)animated {
[self tableView:tableView configureRowsAtIndexPaths:tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows animated:animated];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView configureRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths animated:(BOOL)animated {
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell) {
        [self tableView:tableView configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:animated];
    }
}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated {
// Cell configuration
}
```

what is the best way to implement this

Comment: Have you taken a look at tableView(_:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:? - this is called before a cell is drawn, as described in the docs - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to set a custom class for the cell and override prepareForReuse and cancel download refrenced to imageview like in my case

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        // cancel downloading of the imageView
    }
```